# If $S$ and $T$ are subrings of $R$, is $S+T$ a subring of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $S$ and $T$ are subrings of $R$, is $S+T=\{s+t\mid s\in S, t\in T\}$ a subring of $R$?

So I think that $S+T$ is a subring, but I am getting stuck trying to prove it.

Clearly since $S$ and $T$ are rings, $0,1\in S$ and $0,1\in T$. So, $0+0=0\in S+T$ and $0+1=1\in S+T$.

Then if $a,b\in S+T$ then there exist $s_1,s_2\in S$ and $t_1,t_2\in T$ such that $a=s_1+t_1$ and $b=s_2+t_2$.

So $a+b=(s_1+t_1)+(s_2+t_2) = s_1+(t_1+s_2)+t_2=s_1+(s_2+t_1)+t_2 = (s_1+s_2)+(t_1+t_2)\in S+T$

Also $-a = -(s_1+t_1) = (-s_1)+(-t_1)\in S+T$.

So the only think left that needs to be shown is $ab\in S+T$. So $ab=(s_1+t_1)(s_2+t_2)=s_1s_2+s_1t_2+t_1s_2+t_1t_2$.

This is where I am stuck. I'm not sure how to continue so I am I wrong in saying that $S+T$ is a subring of $R$? If so I am having difficulty thinking of a counter example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ring $S$: the rationals, viewed as a subring of the reals;

Ring $T$: the reals of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Note that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}$ is not in $S+T$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $R = \mathbb{C}$ and consider the subfields $S = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}] = \{a+bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $T = \mathbb{R}$. Then $S + T = \{a + bi \mid a \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. This contains $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$, but not $i\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S+T$ is a subring. Then, for every $s\in S$ and $t\in T$,
$$
(s+0)(0+t)=st\in S+T
$$
Thus you only need to find a counterexample to this situation. A simple one is given by $S=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $T=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ as subrings of $\mathbb{R}$. The sum is the $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace spanned by $1$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, which does not contain $\sqrt{6}=\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{3}$.